# How do exchanges work with Ethereum?

Tags: transactions, exchanges, cold-storage

I'm about to create an exchange and I want to trade ether on it.  But I'm quite confused of how to handle my clients' wallets.

I see that some exchanges like Poloniex receive the ether in my deposit address and withdraw it to their cold wallet, ok, but how can I implement this on my server?

Is there an easy way to automatically create new user's account and redirect its transactions to my cold Ethereum wallet?

Answer (score 4):

[You can write javascript code](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) to open accounts and start transactions to your cold wallet. Basically you install a Ethereum node (for now [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) is the best alternative here) on your server and interface your exchange program with `web3` scripts that you can attach over ipc or json-rpc to the node.